Magento 2, Make Email Address Field in Checkout Page as Optional
Magento 2, Make Email Address Field in Checkout Page as Optional
Custom Module to make checkout page email address field as a optional, if not add default email Id in checkout email address field.
Tried to override the checkout module,but not working

email is the core identifier for the customer... you can rename that to something else. if email is optional - how will you identify the customer?

Using Mobile Number....
